# <p:calendar> button is hidden when disabled="true", how to make it appear anyway?

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces, calendar, disabled-input

```
<p:calendar ... disabled="#{bean.disabled}" />
```

When enabled, you can see the button that opens the popup:

[image: Here you can see the button that call to pop up calendar]

When disabled, this button disappears:

[image: Now this button disappear in disabled mode]

I would like to show button in disabled mode too. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why this button disappear in disabled mode, should be shown

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the 'p:' tag prefix, I imagine you use primefaces.

The button is disabled, because it makes no sense for the popup to appear, the user won't be able to modify the date in the component.

What do you want to achieve?

If you want to disable the input textbox and force the user to use the date picker popup, you can use the readonlyInput=true property.

Comment: Your answer is better solution for @Alice.

Comment: Hi gybangi, sry for my late reply

Comment: thank you for your answer, but my question is not like that

Comment: In disabled mode, this button totally cannot see. I just want to see this button in disabled mode, but it doesn't need to popup when this button click because it is in disabled mode, right?

Comment: I just want to see this button not for pop up .

Comment: @Alice
I don't think primefaces supports that out-of-the-box, but you can try something like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yf7tbkft/1/) 
For this you have to add the jstl core in the `<html>` tag (`xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" `)
Basically, you add another, always disabled button with the same style and attributes as the primefaces one.

Answer (score 1):

```
// this function make the button in disabled mode
function disableCalendar(){
    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger ").prev().attr("disabled","disabled");
    $(":button").filter(".ui-datepicker-trigger ").attr("disabled","disabled");

}
// this function remove the disabled mode
function abilitaCalendar(){
    $(":button").filter(".ui-datepicker-trigger ").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger ").prev().removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.